# Send email notification from a web app

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm building a web app from which I need to send out email notifications to the users who subscribe for them. Say my domain name is `mywebapp.com`. I'm using Google Apps to host my email service currently. Ideally I would like to send all my notifications using Google Apps itself and that's what I've been doing all this while using `msmtp`. But then Google Apps has a limit to the number of emails that can be sent per day which is around 4000 emails.

*So is it possible to use Google Apps to host my primary email service for mywebapp.com and then run my own email server to just send email from say `notification@mywebapp.com`.*

This way, I can still use google apps for checking my regular email and also eliminate the upper limit on the number of emails I can send out per day, since I'll be running my own server.

*Also, what packages do I need to install on Ubuntu?*

I've looked at postfix, but as far as my understanding goes it is a package that can fetch email. Can I use it to send email using a cron job for example?

Links to useful resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is not really a tool to "fetch mail". That is "fetchmail" :-)

Depending on where is hosted your web app, you may already have a local SMTP server available to send your mails (supplied by most providers).

If not, Postfix (or any other MTA, or in other words, "SMTP server") is what you need. You should configure it just to send mail, without being responsible for any domain. This configuration is mostly "out-of-the-box" - but a minimum knowledge is suggested.

In that case, start with "www.postfix.org".

Comment: I realised that about postfix a little while later, after reading up more! :)

Comment: http://www.linode.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3946
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24672

I found these articles helpful and almost got what I wanted! Thanks :)